# Access logs captured with os_log from within the iOS app

Tags: ios, macos, logging, oslog

As of 2021, is it possible to access the logs captured with the [os_log](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) within the iOS app programmatically, for example, to send the log archive over the network?

On the page I've linked, there is a line:

> You can also access log messages programmatically using the OSLog
> framework.

Which leads to the [OSLog](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/oslog) framework page, available only on macOS 10.15+.

Is there any way to get the logs out on the iOS, without connecting the device to the computer and using the Console app, or asking a user to collect analytics and mail it to us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, available with [iOS 15](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/oslog)